# What does `ExpressionNoIn` mean in the ECMAScript spec?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm doing a bit of a deep dive into the for loop and encountered `ExpressionNoIn` in the spec at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.3

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained in [section 11.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) "Comma Operator ( , )":

[image: Comma Operator ECMA Spec]

The `*NoIn` has the same structure, except that in excludes the use of the `in` keyword, section 11.8 "Relational Operators":

[image: Relational Operators ECMA Spec]

The spec says:

> The "NoIn" variants are needed to avoid confusing the `in` operator in a relational expression with the `in` operator in a `for` statement.

As `in` may be used in two ways:

```
for (var x in foo) { ... }
```

Or:

```
if ('x' in foo) { ... }
```

The "NoIn" variants are there to make it impossible to use the second version of `in` above in the first expression of the `for` loop. So, the following code is invalid:

```
for (y = 'x' in foo; y; y = false) { ... }
```

Comment: Ok, I've read that 4 times and it's beginning to makes sense. This is dense and deep stuff.

Comment: It's clicked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`ExpressionNoIn` is a non terminal from which all expressions can be derived, expect the `in` operation (i.e. `'prop' in obj`).

Follow [A3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.3) from the bottom (where `ExpressionNoIn` is defined) to the first `*NoIn` non-terminal which does not contain a (different) `*NoIn` non-terminal anymore:

```
RelationalExpression :
    ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression > ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression <= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression >= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression

RelationalExpressionNoIn :
    ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpressionNoIn < ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpressionNoIn > ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpressionNoIn <= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpressionNoIn >= ShiftExpression
    RelationalExpressionNoIn instanceof ShiftExpression
```

I guess that makes it easier to distinguish `for` loops from `for/in` loops.